# Wrap text around overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

I  have the main div containing some texts, and 2 other divs., which are overlapping the main div. But the text in the main div is overlapped by the other 2 divs. I want the text in the main div to wrap around the overlapped divs.

This question or code may be silly but please do help me out.

```css
.project1,
.project2 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #88c1dc;
  width: 40%;
  height: 50px;
  z-index: 11;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.project1 {
  top: 460px;
}

.project2 {
  top: 540px;
}

.project_title_heading {
  padding-top: 8px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container" style="padding-top: 100px;  height: 100vh; position: relative;">
    <div class="portfolio" style="background: #2186B0; position: absolute; z-index: 10; left: 29%; padding: 30px; height: 80vh; border-radius: 20px;">
      <p style="text-align: justify; font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px;">Lorem ipsum text here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project1">
      <h3 class="project_title_heading"><a href="">Project 1</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="project2">
      <h3 class="project_title_heading"><a href="">Project 2</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3TeHn.png)

Comment: Are you saying that you want project 1 and project 2 to be inside the sea colored container?

Comment: like that? - https://ibb.co/LrX7PC2

Comment: No Daniel. The 2 divs will be just overlapping the main div, but the text in the main div should get wrapped around the 2 divs. Is it possible?

Comment: Say, for example, the main div has a lot of contents(text) in it, the text should not get hidden by the 2 overlapping divs

Comment: is the "main div" the "portfolio" div or the "container" div?

Comment: Main div is the portfolio div

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried embedding the sub-div's in the main div? Try below:

```
<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container" style="padding-top: 100px;  height: 100vh; position: relative;">
    <div class="portfolio" style="background: #2186B0; position: absolute; z-index: 10; left: 29%; padding: 30px; height: 80vh; border-radius: 20px;">
      <p style="text-align: justify; font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px;">Lorem ipsum text here...</p>
      
      <!--New placement-->
      <div class="project1">
          <h3 class="project_title_heading"><a href="">Project 1</a></h3>
      </div>
      <div class="project2">
          <h3 class="project_title_heading"><a href="">Project 2</a></h3>
      </div>
      <!--New placement-->

    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Tried it. Doesn't help. Just the divs comes inside the main div. But the text in the main div doesnot get wrapped around

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you really want to achieve - my guess is that you want the children of the container to float side by side.
If my guess is right, then the below might help - you can add your own styles

```
#portfolio>.container{
   display:flex;
   flex-wrap:wrap;
   justify-content:space-between;
 }
 #portfolio>.container>*{
   width:30%;
 }



<section id="portfolio">
  <div class="container" style="padding-top: 100px;  height: 100vh; position: relative;">
    <div class="portfolio" style="background: #2186B0;">
      <p style="text-align: justify; font-weight: 500; font-size: 18px;">Lorem ipsum text here...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="project1">
      <h3 class="project_title_heading"><a href="">Project 1</a>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="project2">
      <h3 class="project_title_heading"><a href="">Project 2</a></h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
```

As a side note, avoid using inline styling as much as you can

Comment: Yes, initially to make minor changes I use inline styling, gradually I move everything to css file.

Comment: Tried,. didn't help.

Comment: I found some comments in stackoverflow saying, text wrapping isn't possible when the divs are overlapping. Hence I shifted the text and div away from each other so that the 2 divs don't overlap the text in the main div.